# Exceptions when rolling back a transaction - connection already closed?

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework 6.0.0, I'm seeing an exception when closing a transaction.

We'd been having problems with concurrent changes to the table, so I wrapped it in a transaction, and now I'm getting exceptions on rollback.

The code:

```
public LockInfo getSharedLock(string jobid)
{
    using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext())
    {
        using (var transaction = myDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                this.logger.log("Attempting to get shared lock for {0}", jobid);

                var mylocks =
                    myDbContext.joblocks.Where(j => j.customerid == this.userContext.customerid)
                        .Where(j => j.jobid == jobid)
                        .Where(j => j.operatorid == this.userContext.operatorid);

                var exclusiveLock = mylocks.FirstOrDefault(
                    j => j.lockstatus == LockInfo.LockState.Exclusive);
                if (exclusiveLock != null)
                {
                    this.logger.log("{0} already had exclusive lock, ignoring", jobid);
                    return LockInfo.populate(exclusiveLock);
                }

                var sharedLock = mylocks.FirstOrDefault(
                    j => j.lockstatus == LockInfo.LockState.Shared);
                if (sharedLock != null)
                {
                    this.logger.log("{0} already had shared lock, ignoring", jobid));
                    sharedLock.lockdt = DateTime.Now;
                    myDbContext.SaveChanges();

                    return LockInfo.populate(sharedLock);
                }

                var joblock = new joblock
                {
                    customerid = this.userContext.customerid,
                    operatorid = this.userContext.operatorid,
                    jobid = jobid,
                    lockstatus = LockInfo.LockState.Shared,
                    sharedLock.lockdt = DateTime.Now
                };

                myDbContext.joblocks.Add(joblock);
                myDbContext.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();

                this.logger.log("Obtained shared lock for {0}", jobid);
                return LockInfo.populate(joblock);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                this.logger.logException(ex, "Exception in getSharedLock(\"{0}\")", jobid);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the logging, in the code above. We have logging enabled in the database, too.  The log trace:

```
===================
NORMAL    TicketLockController.getLock("AK2015818002WL")
===================
SQL    Opened connection at 9/22/2015 2:47:49 PM -05:00
===================
SQL    Started transaction at 9/22/2015 2:47:49 PM -05:00
===================
NORMAL    Attempting to get shared lock for AK2015818002WL
===================
SQL    SELECT TOP (1) [Extent1].[customerid] AS [customerid]
    ,[Extent1].[jobid] AS [jobid]
    ,[Extent1].[lockdtdate] AS [lockdtdate]
    ,[Extent1].[lockdttime] AS [lockdttime]
    ,[Extent1].[operatorid] AS [operatorid]
    ,[Extent1].[lockstatus] AS [lockstatus]
    ,[Extent1].[changes] AS [changes]
FROM [dbo].[joblock] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[customerid] = 'TESTTK')
    AND ([Extent1].[jobid] = 'AK2015818002WL')
    AND ([Extent1].[operatorid] = 'ADMIN')
    AND (N'Exclusive' = [Extent1].[lockstatus])
===================
SQL    SELECT TOP (1) [Extent1].[customerid] AS [customerid]
    ,[Extent1].[jobid] AS [jobid]
    ,[Extent1].[lockdtdate] AS [lockdtdate]
    ,[Extent1].[lockdttime] AS [lockdttime]
    ,[Extent1].[operatorid] AS [operatorid]
    ,[Extent1].[lockstatus] AS [lockstatus]
    ,[Extent1].[changes] AS [changes]
FROM [dbo].[joblock] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[customerid] = 'TESTTK')
    AND ([Extent1].[jobid] = 'AK2015818002WL')
    AND ([Extent1].[operatorid] = 'ADMIN')
    AND (N'Shared' = [Extent1].[lockstatus])
===================
SQL    INSERT [dbo].[joblock] (
    [customerid]
    ,[jobid]
    ,[lockdtdate]
    ,[lockdttime]
    ,[operatorid]
    ,[lockstatus]
    ,[changes]
    )
VALUES (
    @0
    ,@1
    ,@2
    ,@3
    ,@4
    ,@5
    ,NULL
    )
===================
SQL    Closed connection at 9/22/2015 2:47:50 PM -05:00
===================
EXCEPTION    Unhandled exception caught: The underlying provider failed on Rollback.
===================
EXCEPTION    Inner Exception: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connection
```

The two selects are succeeding, then the insert is failing for some reason. throwing an exception, and for some reason the connection is closing before the Rollback() executes.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

==== Adding stack traces ====

Stacktrace for the outer exception:

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Rollback()
   at korterra.kt_api.Shared.TicketLockWrangler.getSharedLock(String jobid)
   at korterra.kt_ws.ApiControllers.Shared.TicketLockController.getSharedLock(TicketLockDTO ticketLockDTO)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__18`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Stacktrace for the inner exception:

```
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionInterceptionContext.WithConnection(DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbTransactionDispatcher.Rollback(DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityTransaction.Rollback()
```

Comment: Post the full exception ToString. Your error logging is insufficient.

Comment: Also, you are not committing the transactions in many cases. Is that really intentional?

Comment: I can't recreate this on demand. It's something that shows up intermittently in our QA environment. I've never seen it in dev. The only info I have other than what I've already posted is the stack trace, which simply indicates that the exception occurred in the code I posted.

Comment: I'm not committing in execution paths that don't change the database. But perhaps I should.

Comment: OK, I can't spot the error. You desperately need to revise your error logging so that it does not throw away so much information. From the stack trace we could have seen the call and line where this happens.

Comment: I have the stack trace, and it tells me the function- but not the line - where the exception was thrown. And the function is the code I posted. What else is there, in the exception, that would be of use?

Comment: The exception was not thrown in this method. It was thrown in a library. Could you provide the stack trace?

Comment: Done.  We're getting the exception within RollBack(), which we knew. What I just noticed, though, is that we're doing the RollBack() before we log the exception that causes us to rollback. I'll move that, maybe it will help figure out what is going on.

Comment: So the rollback exception causes the original exception to get lost. You should delete that Rollback anyway since it does nothing. Disposing an uncommitted transaction rolls back. Besides this I have no idea what could cause the problem. Maybe you called Rollback after Commit? Try doing that deliberately to see if the same error comes up. Also, delete the rollback call.

Comment: I'm looking at instances when this happened, and I think the original problem was that we weren't committing the changes, when we had an existing shared lock. I'm still not sure why were seeing exceptions in the rollback...

Comment: I am getting the exact same error in EF 6.2 on .NET framework 4.6.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After the discussion, I started logging the exception before trying to roll back - and that revealed the error.

The transaction was deadlocked:

```
Exception in getSharedLock("ticketnumber123456"): An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Inner Exception: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

Inner Exception: Transaction (Process ID 139) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

From what I'm reading, when your told a transaction has been made a deadlock victim, it's already been rolled back. Perhaps that is why we're getting an exception?

The fix seems to be either to recognize when we've deadlocked, and not rollback, or to not use transactions, and retry when we get a primary key violation.

Comment: You should not call Rollback ever in this piece of code. Also, this is an EF bug. It should not crash. It should report an API usage error or something using a clean exception. Could you open a GitHub issue at the EF repo for this?

Comment: I'm currently trying not using transactions, but simply retrying when the underlying records have changed - optimistic locking.

Comment: @usr Could you explain more on why one should not "call the Rollback ever in this piece of code" - what does that mean? Is this a bad usage of the Rollback-feature?

Comment: If the server detects that two transactions have deadlocked, it will choose one of them to kill. When it does this it will rollback the transaction and send the client a error. You, as the client, do not want to rollback the transaction in this case, because the transaction has already been rolled back, and trying to do it again will create another error.