# How should I properly handle CommandTimeout when calling ExecuteSqlCommand

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, hangfire

I have some long running commands in stored procedures that are at risk of timing out, and I run them using `Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`

It would appear that when a command times out, it leaves a lock in the database because the transaction is not rolled back.

I found an explanation for that here: [CommandTimeout – How to handle it properly?](http://blog.sqlxdetails.com/commandtimeout-how-to-handle-it-properly/)

Based on the linked [example](http://blog.sqlxdetails.com/commandtimeout-how-to-handle-it-properly-code-example/) I changed my code to:

```
Database database = Context.Database;
try
{
    return database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
}
catch (SqlException e)
{
    //Transactions can stay open after a CommandTimeout, 
    //so need to rollback any open transactions
    if (e.Number == -2) //CommandTimeout occurred
    {
        //Single rollback exits all levels of nested transactions,
        //no need to loop.
        database.ExecuteSqlCommand("IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK TRAN;");
    }
    throw;
}
```

However, that threw an exception inside the catch, because the connection is now null:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connection
```

Following the comments from Annie and usr I changed my code to this:

```
Database database = Context.Database;
using (var tran = database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        int result = database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);
        tran.Commit();
        return result;
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        var debug = database.SqlQuery<Int16>("SELECT @@SPID");
        tran.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

I really thought that would do it, but the locks in the database continue to accumulate when I set my `CommandTimeout` to a really small value to test it out.

I put a breakpoint at the throw, so I know the transaction has been rolled back. The debug variable tells me the session id and when I check my locks using this query: `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks`, I find a match for the session id in the `request_session_id`, but it's a lock that was already there, not one of the new ones, so I'm a bit confused.

So, how should I properly handle `CommandTimeout` when using `ExecuteSqlCommand` to ensure locks are released immediately?

I downloaded `sp_whoisactive` and ran it, the spid appears to be linked to a query on tables used by Hangfire - I am using Hangfire to run the long running queries in a background process. So, I think that perhaps I am barking up the wrong tree. I did have a problem with locking but I've rewritten my own queries to avoid locking too many rows and I've disabled lock escalation on the tables where I had a problem. These last locks may be coming from Hangfire, and may not be significant, nonetheless I've decided to go with `XACT_ABORT ON` for now.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/working-with-transaction-in-entity-framework-6-0/ see this article. use context.Database.BeginTransaction(), commit, and rollback

Comment: @Annie I'm afraid that didn't work - see my edit

Comment: Rollback always rolls back and no locks will remain. This means that either that rollback line was not called (at the time you checked) or your check is wrong. Maybe you are looking at locks from another session. Btw, you can delete the catch and rollback. That's the default if there is no commit. Common anti pattern.

Comment: @usr I force a command to timeout by setting the timeout to 1s, then I put a breakpoint on the line immediately after the `tran.Rollback()`, then I interrogate the database, and it certainly _looks_ like the locks are incrementing. If they aren't coming from this, I'm baffled. I wonder if it is best just to set XACT_ABORT ON?

Comment: Determine the session ID using SQL Profiler or `SELECT @@SPID` from your application. Then, query the locks of that session. There will be none. Use sp_who2 or sp_whoisactive to find out who is producing those locks.

Comment: this may help on what is happening under the hood : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10929/10825

Comment: @usr I edited my question with more information after I followed your advice.

Comment: Hangfire should not do anything on your connection, right? How is it possible that you are seeing hangfire stuff and your stuff on the same SPID? Are you doing some weird connection sharing or pooling? Maybe your dependency injection framework is handing out the same connection to multiple consumers?

Comment: @usr Hangfire picks up the dependency injection used in my MVC project, so I guess that's a possibility. Is the `request_session_id` definitely the same beast as the `spid`? BTW I'm with you on this "Rollback" technique being an anti pattern. I just got an error on Rollback, I assume because the process was a deadlock victim and EF had already rolled it back: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32771724

Comment: You can see in the debugger if the connection is being shared by calling GetHashCode on the object.